# NSURLSession data task - Process retrieved data

Tags: ios, ios7, background

I want my iOS app to download some product information from a server in background. It should work when app active and inactive mode.

Using `NSURLSessionDataTask` I could fetch the data. But could not process the data in inactive mode.

Can you please guide me if, I can process the data when app is in background/inactive state? Or any other suggestion.

See my code below:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDataTask *sessinURLResData = [session dataTaskWithURL:urlIs completionHandler:^(NSData * dataa,NSURLResponse *response,NSError * error){
    responseData = dataa;// process the data and save in local DB
}];
[sessinURLResData resume];
```

Comment: I Observed its same with NSURLSessionDownloadTask. Is it how NSSessionURL works? Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I want fetch data even app in background.Following code downloading the data but not reaching completionHandler until app comes to fore ground.NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];NSURLSessionDataTask * sessinURLResData = [session dataTaskWithURL:urlIs completionHandler:^(NSData * dataa,NSURLResponse * response,NSError * error){responseData = dataa;// process the data and save in local DB}];[sessinURLResData resume];

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two types of background fetches:

1. If you want your app to periodically check for data while not running in the foreground, you can enable "background fetch" in the app's "capabilities", and then your app delegate perform that fetch in `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`. You can only do quick (30 sec or less) network requests. But your app would do the network request, and call the appropriate completion handler code from the app delegate, reporting either the failure, the presence new data, or the lack of new data:

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
   {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."];
       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
       NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           if (error) {
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
               return;
           }

           BOOL foundNewData;

           // parse the data; setting `foundNewData` as appropriate

           if (foundNewData) {
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
           } else {
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
           }
       }];

       [task resume];
   }
   ```
2. A completely different type of background network request is that of a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, great for doing large downloads/uploads in the background. For this, any downloads/uploads you initiate will continue even when the app is no longer in foreground (even if the app is terminated) and when they're all done, your app will be restarted if necessary and the appropriate delegate methods will be called. But, to do this, you must:

   - use `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:identifier]`;
   - use delegate-based `NSURLSession` (which you are);
   - use download or upload tasks, not data tasks;
   - use the download/upload task factory method that does *not* use completion block (you must implement the delegate methods);
   - have the app delegate respond to `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`, capturing the `completionHandler`; and
   - implement `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` in the session delegate, which will call the `completionHandler` when you're done processing everything.

There are other techniques for doing background requests, but these are the two main iOS7 specific background networking. You have not told us which of these you are using, nor shown us enough code to diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: what would be the other way of doing ? You specify that with NSURLSessionConfiguration you can't use a data task. That's not good for me since I don't download/upload a file (I'm just sending and Http post request to a server)

Comment: It's not that you can't use data task with `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, but rather that you can't use data task with background session (which I'm sure is what you meant). But, setting that aside, even if you're not uploading or downloading anything, just use download or upload task, regardless. For example, treat it as a download task and the "download" is merely the response you got from your server (e.g. whatever response your server sends you). Just because it's a download task doesn't mean you have to actually save the response as a file anywhere...